# How can I get the Value of a Control by iterating through its parent ControlPanel

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, controlpanel

I'm dynamically populating a ControlPanel with some controls... Some are DropDowns, some are TextBoxes:

```
//inputArray is a JsonArray (thus the SelectToken methods)

foreach (var item in inputArray)
{
    //Create Label
    Label LabelTitle = new Label();
    LabelTitle.Text = (string)item.SelectToken("title");
    Panel_Controls.Controls.Add(LabelTitle);

    //Create Control
    if ((string)item.SelectToken("type") == "textinput")
    {
        TextBox TextBox_Control = new TextBox();
        TextBox_Control.ID = (string)item.SelectToken("title");
        Panel_Controls.Controls.Add(TextBox_Control);
    }
    if ((string)item.SelectToken("type") == "dropdown")
    {
        DropDownList DropDown_Control = new DropDownList();
        DropDown_Control.DataSource = dropDownData;
        DropDown_Control.DataBind();
        Panel_Controls.Controls.Add(DropDown_Control);
    }
}
```

Later on, I need to get the values of the DropDown and Text box fields. I can filter out the Label and other controls. I can't figure out how to get the values of the Controls within the foreach statement. I'm guessing I need to Cast the control as something that will let me get a .Value property, because the generic Control won't give me a .Value property.

```
foreach (Control item in Panel_Controls.Controls)
{
    if (!(item is Label | item is LiteralControl))
    {
        //How can I access the .Value of the controls here?
    }
}
```

Could someone suggest a good way of getting values from TextBox and DropDowns within the foreach loop?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to cast item to the appropriate control type to access it's properties.

```
if (!(item is Label | item is LiteralControl))
{
      if(item is TextBox)
      {
        TextBox textBox = (TextBox)item;
        string textValue = textBox.Text;
      }
      ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use Linq to get an `IEnumerable` of Textboxes and an `IEnumerable` of DropDownLists:

```
IEnumerable<TextBox> txts = Panel_Controls.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
IEnumerable<DropDownList> ddls = Panel_Controls.Controls.OfType<DropDownList>();
```

The result enumerables already have the correct types. That way you can iterate through the enumerables individually, since what you do with each item is different, depending on the type.

The end result is that you will not have a buch of `IF` inside you loop: you will have two iteration blocks:

```
foreach(TextBox txt in txts)
{
    //your textbox code
}

foreach(DropDownList ddl in ddls)
{
    //your dropdownlist code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should cast the item to the Textbox like:

```
TextBox textbox = item as TextBox;
if (textbox != null)
    string text = textbox.Text;
```

You can do the same for any other control

Comment: -1 You have to check the type before casting or else you will get an error when casting something that's no a TextBox

Comment: @Adrian - Technically that is not true when using 'as' to cast... it will just return a null value if the cast fails.  Therefore, the error will be a NullReferenceException on the next line.

Comment: You're are right @Philip. I will remove downvote once @peer adjusts his code to check for nullity

Comment: I also just noticed that peer says 'cast the item to the Label', but in the sample actually casts to a TextBox... oops!  :)

Comment: @Adrian - It's only intended to show how to get a value, no production code ;). Fixed the Label -> Textbox

Comment: You should also check if `textbox` is null before trying to access it

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the Text property of the controls?  That way you won't have to care what type of control it is.  What type do you need the value to be?  Will string do?

```
foreach (Control item in Panel_Controls.Controls)
{
   string value = item.Text;
   // do something with the value
}
```